# Session for Java servlet and php, are they the same?

Tags: java, php

I have a web application project in which i develop Java servlets along with php. I have designed the client log in application based on Java servlets and display of databases using mysql query from php. I am developing these using xampp on localhost for php and tomcat server for my Java servlet.

My question is, do they share the same session? For example, this would mean that the client logs in using a Java servlet and client can log out (destroy session) using php code.

Comment: No, not natively. You could, however, use SSO functionality to establish the session across applications. Maybe [Shibboleth](http://shibboleth.internet2.edu/).

Comment: No php and J2EE do not share the same session. You could however write your own session and use that to keep the session between two.

Answer (score 0):

Nope, they don't share the session info. Java and php run on two different VM, and unless you've configured them to share this kind of information, they won't.

Honestly, I have not seen it implemented... IMHO it's just easier to manage the session in one of the VM.

HTH!

Comment: It's not completely uncommon, and it's not even that difficult (depending on what needs to be managed). Also, I imagine that there aren't different virtual machines, looking at the description.

Comment: Yes. That's what SSO is about, and there's Shibboleth, which shares credentials across domains and sites. My comment, however, had to do with sharing user-related authentication authorizations, not necessarily an entire session (which I should have stated). I have actually set this particular thing up with three subdomains, one using ExpressionEngine (the main user account), a YouTube clone site, and a WordPress site.

Comment: "It's not completely uncommon, and it's not even that difficult"

Really? We agree that they're different servers (java and php), and that session information is different and stored differently. How do you make them aware of each other? i.e. if I close my session in php, how would you transmit that info to the JVM? Please elaborate... should I post a new question?

Comment: You create a connector and a single point of logout that dispatches the "end session" method to each related site, which in turn ends the session on that system.

Comment: OK, I see what you mean. Thanks for clarifying.

Comment: "not even that difficult" is a relative thing, too. Depends on the systems involved, I suppose, and it takes some thought and detail for it to work right. But it's definitely doable, in a "you'll need a programmer" sense.

Answer (score 0):

Your requirements / environment is unique. That said they cannot share the same session.

Cookies may help you.